# Module not found error when importing Swift pod into Objective-C project

Tags: objective-c, swift, ios-frameworks, ios-charts, ios-library

I have an existing project which is written in Objective-C. I want to use the [iOS Charts library by Daniel Gindi](https://github.com/danielgindi/ios-charts), which is in Swift, in that project. How can I achieve this?

[importing swift framework into a objective-c project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31099596/importing-swift-framework-into-a-objective-c-project) is related, but in my case I am using the library by installing it through Cocoapods [as instructed here](https://www.codebeaulieu.com/56/How-To-Make-Beautiful-iso-charts-by-example).

In that question, he is at least able to import the header, but in my case I am not able to.

step 1: Create Objective-C single view project.

step 2: Create a Podfile and add following lines -

```
use_frameworks!
pod 'Charts'
```

step 3: Install the pod

step 4: Try to import Charts in ViewController.h by `@import Charts` but it gives an error at this point. The error is - `Module Charts not found`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31099596/importing-swift-framework-into-a-objective-c-project  check this question out, you may find a answer here

Comment: @JoshCaswell My edit clearly specifies why my question is not same as the one specified as duplicate. Please remove the duplicate mark if you find my edit convincing, so that I get solutions soon.

Comment: @satheesh I am also not able to do `@import Charts`

Comment: See also [How to import and use Swift pod framework in ObjC project?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27995691)

Comment: @JoshCaswell Let me give you steps to replicate my problem.
step 1: Create Objective-C single view project.
step 2: Create a Podfile and add following lines - 
`use_frameworks!
pod 'Charts'`
step 3: Install the pod
step 4: Try to import Charts in ViewController.h by `@impot Charts` but it gives error at this point.

Comment: @JoshCaswell done! at least now you might have realized that my question is not a duplicate! Please remove the duplicate mark.

Comment: Are you building your project from xcodeproject or xcworkspace file after installing pod?

Comment: xcworkspace file @Anni S

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In my existing project, I did `#include Charts-Swift.h` in my project's `main.m` file and this solved problem from me. `@import Charts` worked perfectly now. This was done according to the instructions that are written in Apple documentation [here.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html)

I made a new project and tried [Anni S's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33936848/4618125), this time I built the project with `cmd+B` before writing any import statement and it worked too. I guess building it once after installing pod and before importing any module is necessary.

Answer (score 7):

I tried the same step what you mentioned in the comment however I was not getting the error that you got. My project simply builds and runs. Steps that I followed:

1. Create Objective-C single view project.
2. Added 'Podfile' in the project directory level (Podfile should be at the xcodeproject file level) and add following lines

> ```
> use_frameworks!
> pod 'Charts'
> ```

3. Close xcodeproject
4. Go to project directory and run the `'pod install'` command from the termial
5. Open workspace i.e. .xcworkspace file
6. Import charts file in view controller such as

> `#import "ViewController.h" 
>   @import Charts;`

Comment: This worked when I tried your steps with new project but not with my existing project.

Comment: So I guess, you might be missing something in existing project. Just delete all the cocoaPod related files in your existing project and try again the steps mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason why it works for new project, but for an existing project.

In the project settings, delete the value of the Other Linker Flags property.

This is the most case that most developers are being missed.